# Javascript return in eval string

Tags: javascript, eval

I know eval is evil, but in this case please do not point this out please. I am creating something very custom and in my case eval is the only solution (that is what eval is there for).

My problem is that `return` does not work in eval strings. The browser throws and `Illegal return statement` error. Could someone explain to me why this happens?

I would like this string to be eval'ed:

```
eval(`
  console.log('log this');
  return;
  console.log('DONT log this')
`);
```

Here is a stack blitz to play with

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8x8p6m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Return statements are only valid inside functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inputting `console.log('log this'); return; console.log('DONT log this');` in your browser (that's basically what eval is); it'll complain because you're trying to use `return` outside of a function.

However, you can do something like this:

```
eval(`
  (() => {
    console.log('log this');
    return;
    console.log('DONT log this');
  })()
`);
```

Comment: Most simplified answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is why we use `new Function()` instead of `eval()` if we really need `eval()` for something.

If you pass a string to the Function constructor, it will automatically call `eval()` on it. So no need to wrap eval And function in the same statement, that's basically doing the same thing twice.

```js
const js_str = `
  console.log('log this');
  return 'ok';
  console.log('DONT log this')
`;

const result = new Function( js_str )();

console.log( result );
```

If you could explain what you're creating with `eval()`, there might even be a better solution as well.

Comment: Eval is faster to use is this case don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not in a function:

```
eval('(new Function("console.log(1);return;console.log(2)"))()');
```

Logs 1 but not 2.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, return statements are only valid inside functions

Give this a try:

```
eval('(function (){ 
  console.log("log this");
  return 23;
  console.log("do not log this"); 
})()');
```